# How can I display a block content when a button clicked Drupal 7

Tags: commerce, blocks

I want to display a block content when clicking the button on same page in drupal7. it will be like that  "hi" msg and button in same page and when clicking to the button "Welcome to Drupal" should come on the top of the page.How will I do that..

Comment: How did you implement that "button", is that like a form that got submitted? If not can you provide more details about its implementation?